# Safari 6: On an <IMG>, when box-shadow spread set to 0 AND a background-color value is set, no box-shadow is rendered at all

Tags: safari, css

This looks like a recently introduced bug that manifests on both iOS6 and Safari 6. Has anyone else gotten bitten by this?

What might be a work around? What if we really actually needed that box shadow to have spread=0? Right now we can get the shadow to render by setting the spread value to `-1px` or `1px`

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/uCseS/2/

Comment: Hmm. maybe it only manifests on our site. I can't reproduce it with a fiddle.

Comment: In that case, see if you can isolate the issue on your site, and figure out what's going on. A code snippet from your stylesheet would help immensely.

Comment: I got a little more info. If I take out `background-color: white` the behavior becomes normal (0px spread renders the shadow)

Comment: Updated with working reproduction fiddle (only exhibits bad behavior on the flavors of Safari 6, tested on iPad3, iPhone5, and Lion 10.7.4 and Lion 10.7.5)

Comment: Reproduced-ish in Safari 6 on Mountain Lion 10.8.2. On first load, the shadow looks fine; on refreshing, the shadow disappears. Very bizarre.

Comment: Thanks. Are you running 10.8.2 on a MBA by any chance? I want new features but don't want lower battery life.

Comment: Nope - I'm using the late 2010 white MacBook, the last of its kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a bug indeed. However, if you use **rgba** notation for the background-color, the shadow reappears.

```
img{
 background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0);
 box-shadow: #000 2px 2px 10px 0px;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(2px, 5px, 0px); 
} ​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/KuhQp/